# Function never stops running

Tags: javascript, function

I'm building the first part of the Rock-Paper-Scissors project of The Odin Project foundations course and my function playRound works but never stops running

```
function getComputerChoice(){
    //create array of (rock, paper, scissors)
    const listOfWeapons = new Array ('Rock','Paper','Scissors');
    //make computer choose randomly between the objects of the array
    let computerChoice = listOfWeapons[Math.floor(Math.random()*listOfWeapons.length)];
    console.log(computerChoice)
}
getComputerChoice();

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
    let getPlayerSelection = prompt('Choose your weapon!');
    if (getComputerChoice == getPlayerSelection){
        alert('It\'s a tie you both have choosen the same weapon')
    }
    for (getComputerChoice == 'Rock'; getPlayerSelection == 'Paper';){
        alert('You won paper beats rock')
    }
    for (getComputerChoice == 'Rock'; getPlayerSelection == 'Scissors';){
        alert('You lost rock beats scissors')
    }
    for (getComputerChoice == 'Paper'; getPlayerSelection == 'Scissors';){
        alert('You won scissors beats paper')
    }
    for (getComputerChoice == 'Paper'; getPlayerSelection == 'Rock';){
        alert('You lost paper beats rock')
    }
    for (getComputerChoice == 'Scissors'; getPlayerSelection == 'Rock';){
        alert('You won rock beats paper')
    }
    for (getComputerChoice == 'Scissors'; getPlayerSelection == 'Paper';){
        alert('You lost scissors beats paper')
    }
}
playRound();
```

How can I modify this code so the function terminates when it's done? Or should I start over?

Comment: Your `for` syntax is totally incorrect https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: what do you mean by "it works"?

Comment: You should try to understand some basics of the language you are using. Ie how to call functions, what loops and conditions are for, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong:

1. You wanted to use `if`, but you used `for`
2. You have to use and (`&&`) operator to compare many thing in one `if` statement
3. `getComputerChoice` is a function, not a string
4. `getComputerChoice` have return a value
5. `getComputerChoice` have to be called inside `playRound`

```js
function getComputerChoice() {
  //create array of (rock, paper, scissors)
  const listOfWeapons = new Array('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors');
  //make computer choose randomly between the objects of the array
  let computerChoice = listOfWeapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * listOfWeapons.length)];
  console.log(computerChoice)
  return computerChoice
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let getPlayerSelection = prompt('Choose your weapon!');
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice()
  if (computerChoice == getPlayerSelection) {
    alert('It\'s a tie you both have choosen the same weapon')
  }
  if (computerChoice == 'Rock' && getPlayerSelection == 'Paper') {
    alert('You won paper beats rock')
  }
  if (computerChoice == 'Rock' && getPlayerSelection == 'Scissors') {
    alert('You lost rock beats scissors')
  }
  if (computerChoice == 'Paper' && getPlayerSelection == 'Scissors') {
    alert('You won scissors beats paper')
  }
  if (computerChoice == 'Paper' && getPlayerSelection == 'Rock') {
    alert('You lost paper beats rock')
  }
  if (computerChoice == 'Scissors' && getPlayerSelection == 'Rock') {
    alert('You won rock beats paper')
  }
  if (computerChoice == 'Scissors' && getPlayerSelection == 'Paper') {
    alert('You lost scissors beats paper')
  }
}
playRound();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use if else logic not if followed by for. Replace each for with else if in your playRound function like this:

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){
    let getPlayerSelection = prompt('Choose your weapon!');
    if (getComputerChoice == getPlayerSelection){
        alert('It\'s a tie you both have choosen the same weapon')
    }
    else if (getComputerChoice == 'Rock' && getPlayerSelection == 'Paper';){
        alert('You won paper beats rock')
    }
    else if (getComputerChoice == 'Rock' && getPlayerSelection == 'Scissors';){
        alert('You lost rock beats scissors')
    }
    else if (getComputerChoice == 'Paper' && getPlayerSelection == 'Scissors';){
        alert('You won scissors beats paper')
    }
    else if (getComputerChoice == 'Paper' && getPlayerSelection == 'Rock';){
        alert('You lost paper beats rock')
    }
    else if (getComputerChoice == 'Scissors' && getPlayerSelection == 'Rock';){
        alert('You won rock beats paper')
    }
    else {
        alert('You lost scissors beats paper')
    }
}
```